# Python shapely & geopandas in dockerimage

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fiona

I'm trying to build a dockerimage to run a Python script, but I keep getting errors. I searched around a little but and managed to construct the following script, bit I still am receiving errors.

Below you can find the information to reproduce this issue.

My requirements.txt file

```
bs4==0.0.1
PyMySQL==0.10.1
requests==2.24.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
geopandas==0.10.2
Shapely==1.7.1
XlsxWriter==3.0.2
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ADD requirements.txt .

RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev build-base libffi-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    python3 python3-dev gcc \
    gfortran musl-dev g++ \
    libffi-dev openssl-dev \
    libxml2 libxml2-dev \
    libxslt libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev zlib-dev

RUN apk add unixodbc

RUN echo "mirror.leaseweb.com/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add make gcc geos-dev musl-dev



RUN pip3 install virtualenv --no-warn-script-location --disable-pip-version-check
RUN pip3 install --upgrade cython

RUN virtualenv .env --python=python3

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

CMD python -u script.py
```

Error message:

```
...
#16 489.2          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c5c06dfa7a354b268ccdb872d161edca/
#16 489.2     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 489.2     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 489.2     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 489.2     ----------------------------------------
#16 489.2 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/04/31d0a6f03943b1684f32c9b861be40c1fd282468fa6bd54ddf4a774e6b0f/Fiona-1.8.13.tar.gz#sha256=5ec34898c8b983a723fb4e949dd3e0ed7e691c303e51f6bfd61e52ac9ac813ae (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 489.4   Downloading Fiona-1.8.12.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 489.9     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 489.9      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2cb692fd714a4d73936684822bdd69a1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2cb692fd714a4d73936684822bdd69a1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-705j5vsx
#16 489.9          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2cb692fd714a4d73936684822bdd69a1/
#16 489.9     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 489.9     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 489.9     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 489.9     ----------------------------------------
#16 489.9 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/d8/feab39987296437fbdc3029fb39752a14355d217d73b93471010b8dd63a3/Fiona-1.8.12.tar.gz#sha256=c9266ddf6ae2a64fcea20014ddf27f800ac07584f2fdb09c2a02f3b3a52e371c (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 490.0   Downloading Fiona-1.8.11.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 490.4     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 490.4      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c8e969e433694e7b97819c8840b60eab/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c8e969e433694e7b97819c8840b60eab/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9lsi62v6
#16 490.4          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c8e969e433694e7b97819c8840b60eab/
#16 490.4     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 490.4     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 490.4     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 490.4     ----------------------------------------
#16 490.4 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/f4/0a0ddc6174c4a93679b5f1dd3535e7ef8989828e6d5f86112de681f8c87b/Fiona-1.8.11.tar.gz#sha256=1e7ca9e051f5bffa1c43c70d573da9ca223fc076b84fa73380614fc02b9eb7f6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 490.5   Downloading Fiona-1.8.10.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 491.0     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 491.0      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c749e2a8c1b74ba7b1246c6a3a2beeaf/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c749e2a8c1b74ba7b1246c6a3a2beeaf/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-a612e8zu
#16 491.0          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_c749e2a8c1b74ba7b1246c6a3a2beeaf/
#16 491.0     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 491.0     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 491.0     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 491.0     ----------------------------------------
#16 491.0 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/73/f80b491ed8559326fab202a6d6333a3cd6e8be1e9d782bc6c0d03d476457/Fiona-1.8.10.tar.gz#sha256=ff562eb2f3960e21f8c7f050ddd7f47a763869ea14afc2234a40df72666c6a2c (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 491.0   Downloading Fiona-1.8.9.post2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 491.6     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 491.6      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_d862e228461c4ea0872f7919e17813ec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_d862e228461c4ea0872f7919e17813ec/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-pz58kp1p
#16 491.6          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_d862e228461c4ea0872f7919e17813ec/
#16 491.6     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 491.6     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 491.6     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 491.6     ----------------------------------------
#16 491.6 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/52/45e75507660ce0e86176d0f59b659560f687e2c7e9ebf82a10e7dcd2d3b7/Fiona-1.8.9.post2.tar.gz#sha256=210fb038b579fab38f35ddbdd31b9725f4d5099b3edfd4b87c983e5d47b79983 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 491.6   Downloading Fiona-1.8.9.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 492.2     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 492.2      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_5576fbd73baa413d92d45588a3474aa8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_5576fbd73baa413d92d45588a3474aa8/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-st9k95aw
#16 492.2          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_5576fbd73baa413d92d45588a3474aa8/
#16 492.2     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 492.2     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 492.2     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 492.2     ----------------------------------------
#16 492.2 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/a4/d9dd7399be809d3990f5000fb6ae43189ea26ae88be1bed3a4c9ddc1becc/Fiona-1.8.9.post1.tar.gz#sha256=d5e0ea0b8addffe9cba4cb59e2bd495b015230e7a1b1597974f5048211930199 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 492.2   Downloading Fiona-1.8.9.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 492.8     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 492.8      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2617c6ca9be043e2b4da52c0882709bd/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2617c6ca9be043e2b4da52c0882709bd/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-qr9jxe5_
#16 492.8          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_2617c6ca9be043e2b4da52c0882709bd/
#16 492.8     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 492.8     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 492.8     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 492.8     ----------------------------------------
#16 492.8 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/92/dcbd8c54d697c22f299b5af63b6df3acfbd06c6d72e249614c05be99337c/Fiona-1.8.9.tar.gz#sha256=4dd6e2f5327c1174143c7c8594a75d373bc72f2c9a2a6daee312c3186a128add (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 492.9   Downloading Fiona-1.8.8.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
#16 493.5     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 493.5      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8ec8d83afbb0458a8b16afc1b8b87909/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8ec8d83afbb0458a8b16afc1b8b87909/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5tytn5dv
#16 493.5          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8ec8d83afbb0458a8b16afc1b8b87909/
#16 493.5     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 493.5     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 493.5     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 493.5     ----------------------------------------
#16 493.5 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/7f/e288db1ad63d759d494c30caae34f865e0c6927588c490705e91b7134193/Fiona-1.8.8.tar.gz#sha256=711c3be73203b37812992089445a1e4e9d3d6b64e667389f7b15406e15a91e83 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 493.5   Downloading Fiona-1.8.7.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
#16 494.2     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 494.2      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_abdb3fd21ed04e9699f232c5c179028d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_abdb3fd21ed04e9699f232c5c179028d/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-swxtbp5n
#16 494.2          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_abdb3fd21ed04e9699f232c5c179028d/
#16 494.2     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 494.2     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 494.2     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 494.2     ----------------------------------------
#16 494.2 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/62/daafd070aebefa639df247705b97f13f7cfad43895581b5cae41bd886709/Fiona-1.8.7.tar.gz#sha256=a55a23615bad3e142d4e4cda97bb5de83c778a80049222e9dffae93c13b5cf93 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 494.2   Downloading Fiona-1.8.6.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
#16 494.8     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 494.8      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_aa9eaa75c84c4902b498799ac7160933/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_aa9eaa75c84c4902b498799ac7160933/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-1tq758ja
#16 494.8          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_aa9eaa75c84c4902b498799ac7160933/
#16 494.8     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 494.8     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 494.8     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 494.8     ----------------------------------------
#16 494.8 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/9d/63696e7b1de42aad294d4781199a408bec593d8fdb80a2b4a788c911a33b/Fiona-1.8.6.tar.gz#sha256=fa31dfe8855b9cd0b128b47a4df558f1b8eda90d2181bff1dd9854e5556efb3e (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 494.8   Downloading Fiona-1.8.5.tar.gz (1.7 MB)
#16 495.4     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 495.4      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a912667e573f438d9a6f9cdf217b4b30/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a912667e573f438d9a6f9cdf217b4b30/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-nvkf9lba
#16 495.4          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a912667e573f438d9a6f9cdf217b4b30/
#16 495.4     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 495.4     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 495.4     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 495.4     ----------------------------------------
#16 495.4 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/af/1c2c83c4a8363a4ce9fea817b1910b5e071bed012e18257faa2a0ab3cfe7/Fiona-1.8.5.tar.gz#sha256=4f5cc2d449edbbf693c83e24cdada72de7c41297383d16fcc92387eb445e9d35 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 495.4   Downloading Fiona-1.8.4.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
#16 495.9     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 495.9      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a54f92ab7bfe4d47b3f762e5e281fd7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a54f92ab7bfe4d47b3f762e5e281fd7c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-1oe3cyz4
#16 495.9          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_a54f92ab7bfe4d47b3f762e5e281fd7c/
#16 495.9     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 495.9     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 495.9     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 495.9     ----------------------------------------
#16 495.9 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/16/84960540e9fce61d767fd2f0f1d95f4c63e99ab5d8fddc308e8b51b059b8/Fiona-1.8.4.tar.gz#sha256=aec9ab2e3513c9503ec123b1a8573bee55fc6a66e2ac07088c3376bf6738a424 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 495.9   Downloading Fiona-1.8.3.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
#16 496.4     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 496.4      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8d9a9f3d0e61454fbb60179cd1ba049a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8d9a9f3d0e61454fbb60179cd1ba049a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-hd8lraut
#16 496.4          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_8d9a9f3d0e61454fbb60179cd1ba049a/
#16 496.4     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 496.4     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 496.4     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 496.4     ----------------------------------------
#16 496.4 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/d1/fcdb32513a03abfde0d97fd9782ce0f8cc0540fa6c6ce783e87b94064964/Fiona-1.8.3.tar.gz#sha256=3e831100a23c3b6cd32b98baf0c9e2119d909b44a5cf4533d3625f61dcf2d2b1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 496.4   Downloading Fiona-1.8.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
#16 496.9     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 496.9      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_0b555b26cbfd49b7a091cc0c1a3f83bb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_0b555b26cbfd49b7a091cc0c1a3f83bb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-sc5_ge3_
#16 496.9          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_0b555b26cbfd49b7a091cc0c1a3f83bb/
#16 496.9     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 496.9     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 496.9     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 496.9     ----------------------------------------
#16 496.9 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/50/0466d5d83e1859c5ca38351ee932d64cc5635f9d4dad522879e58f4b0018/Fiona-1.8.2.tar.gz#sha256=4c6419b7ac29136708029f6a44b4ccd458735a4d241016c7b1bab41685c08d8f (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 496.9   Downloading Fiona-1.8.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
#16 497.4     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 497.4      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_35ea1756e38449c2a9264a937eefadcd/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_35ea1756e38449c2a9264a937eefadcd/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-pyu6s2pl
#16 497.4          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_35ea1756e38449c2a9264a937eefadcd/
#16 497.4     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 497.4     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 497.4     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 497.4     ----------------------------------------
#16 497.4 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/5f/0c6704efeea2ff3fba7f54cc6ec38070157f21bc1cffa7bdfa7c9f6b8f7a/Fiona-1.8.1.tar.gz#sha256=4c34bb4c5cd788aaf14e5484c3b7de407b1a8a7c7b2d29bbb2e8b37931e83b8d (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 497.4   Downloading Fiona-1.8.0.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
#16 498.0     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#16 498.0      command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_e56477796473486da35dc8961f3df321/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_e56477796473486da35dc8961f3df321/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-x4dz43ke
#16 498.0          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ey3bajqj/fiona_e56477796473486da35dc8961f3df321/
#16 498.0     Complete output (2 lines):
#16 498.0     Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
#16 498.0     A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
#16 498.0     ----------------------------------------
#16 498.0 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/bd/c1efc2680f338e5941121c776d6323af6b9698ac739e22ba523cee348a7f/Fiona-1.8.0.tar.gz#sha256=20141a9ece06daa7bb4333fba640c2fe39a49f8aca5492d1da8595d41e91844a (from https://pypi.org/simple/fiona/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
#16 498.0 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of sqlalchemy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#16 498.0 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#16 498.0 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of requests to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#16 498.0 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pymysql to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#16 498.0 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of bs4 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#16 498.0 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fiona>=1.8 (from geopandas) (from versions: 0.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.10, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.16.1, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.3.post1, 1.6.4, 1.7b1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0.post2, 1.7.1, 1.7.1.post1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.9.post1, 1.7.10, 1.7.10.post1, 1.7.11, 1.7.11.post1, 1.7.11.post2, 1.7.12, 1.7.13, 1.8a1, 1.8a2, 1.8a3, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.9.post1, 1.8.9.post2, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.13.post1, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.8.20)
#16 498.0 ERROR: No matching distribution found for fiona>=1.8
#16 498.1 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
#16 498.1 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'get-listings' failed to build : Build failed
```

Note: message is cropped due to size restrictions.

If I understand the error correctly, it fails to install fiona, however I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue: using conda did the trick

My Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/minimal-notebook
FROM python:3.7
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

USER root
# Installing geopandas and all it's dependencies
RUN conda install -c conda-forge movingpandas && \
    conda clean --all -f -y && \
    rm -rf /home/$NB_USER/.cache/yarn 

RUN conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```

Have fun with it!